# i am facing an issue using firebase for signup its called three times in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to react js i am using firebase for authentication.. hope someone can help me solve this problem why my sign up component called three times.
**here is my signup Component**

```
   this.state = {
      displayName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    }; 
   //this is a form submit method
   handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords don't match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );

      await createUserProfileDocument(user, { displayName });

      this.setState({
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

**here is my app.js function**

```
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              currentUser: {
                id: snapshot.id,
                ...snapshot.data(),
              },
            }
          );
          console.log(this.state.currentUser);
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ currentUser: userAuth });
      }
    });
  }
```

**console output why it calling three times when i click sign up button**

```
 App.js:33 
    {id: "U43Vz2cgEETiWNMoPsXhXDU82Hz1", displayName: "hgh", email: "tmh3000@yahoo.com", createdAt: t}
    App.js:33 
    {id: "U43Vz2cgEETiWNMoPsXhXDU82Hz1", displayName: null, createdAt: t, email: "tmh3000@yahoo.com"}
    App.js:33 
    {id: "U43Vz2cgEETiWNMoPsXhXDU82Hz1", createdAt: t, email: "tmh3000@yahoo.com", displayName: "hgh"}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I think It is happening because the **state** of the **currentUser** changed three times.

See **displayName** property value First it was **"hgh"** then **"null"** again **"hgh"**

As per react when the **state** **changes** component **re-renders**.

Comment: so is it okay to call three times if not so what should i do to stop it calling three times